# How to split one iterator into two?

Tags: python

How would you split one iterator into two without iterating twice or using additional memory to store all the data?

Solution when you can store everything in memory:

```
l = [{'a': i, 'b': i * 2} for i in range(10)]
def a(iterator):
    for item in iterator:
        print(item)
def b(iterator):
   for item in iterator:
        print(item)

a([li['a'] for li in l])
b([li['b'] for li in l])
```

or if you can iterate twice,

```
class SomeIterable(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(10):
            yield {'a': i, 'b': i * 2}


def a(some_iterator):
    for item in some_iterator:
        print(item)


def b(some_iterator):
    for item in some_iterator:
        print(item)


s = SomeIterable()

a((si['a'] for si in s))
b((si['b'] for si in s))
```

But how would I make it if I just want to iterate once?

Comment: Without iterating twice or using additional memory? You don't.

Comment: If `a` must complete before `b` begins, this is literally impossible. If that isn't a requirement, the problem is still a huge pain; you either need to rewrite `a` and `b`, or you need to use threads.

Comment: basically,  i want one iteration of a to complete then one iteration of b, then again a, then again b... that way you don't have to make a list of the whole iterator.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but seems to be you can do one for loop and separate 'a', 'b' appropriately?

Comment: Your question is puzzling, but have you tried `itertools.tee` ?

Comment: By the way, your `SomeIterator` class is not actually an iterator. An iterator has a `__next__` (or `next` in Python 2) method, in addition to an `__iter__` method that returns itself. Your class is more appropriately described as an "iterable".

Comment: @hpaulj: That stores all the data in memory, though.

Comment: Well how about actually constructing your iterable how you would like to use it.

Comment: ok, to clarify, the iterable `s` is huge.  each item in it takes a while to compute and takes a lot of memory.  `a` and `b` are external library functions that I cannot modify easily that take an iterator and generate some output when done iterating over the whole iterator.

Doesn't `tee` use additional memory?

Comment: @lqdc I understand that the `a` and `b` that you're showing are simple examples to show what you want and not the real ones, but does `a` really need to go through the whole dataset before running `b`? Would it be ok to supply just one element to `a`, then to `b`, and then go to the next in the generator?

Comment: @Ricardo 
No, they are not my functions. so i can't modify them. Also they are the kind of functions that do not store state.  An example is a trie from `marisa-trie` package. 


    >>> import marisa_trie
    >>> trie = marisa_trie.Trie(['key1', 'key2', 'key12'])  

Here each key takes a long time to generate and the whole thing cannot be stored in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the clarification in the comments, `a` and `b` are external library functions you cannot rewrite, but it's okay to interleave their execution. In that case, what you want is possible, but it pretty much requires threads:

```
import multiprocessing.pool # for ThreadPool, not multiprocessing
import Queue

_endofinput = object()

def _queueiter(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        if item is _endofinput:
            break
        yield item

def parallel_execute(funcs, iterable, maxqueue):
    '''Interleaves the execution of funcs[0](iterable), funcs[1](iterable), etc.

    No function is allowed to lag more than maxqueue items behind another.
    (This will require adjustment if a function might return before consuming
    all input.)

    Makes only one pass over iterable.

    '''

    queues = [Queue.Queue(maxsize=maxqueue) for func in funcs]
    queueiters = [_queueiter(queue) for queue in queues]
    threadpool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=len(funcs))

    results = threadpool.map_async(lambda (f, x): f(x), zip(funcs, queueiters))

    for item in iterable:
        for queue in queues:
            queue.put(item)

    for queue in queues:
        queue.put(_endofinput)

    threadpool.close()
    return results.get()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the functions that consume your two iterators are not under your control and don't return control of the program to your code before consuming all of the iterator contents, there is no way to do what you want. You'll either need to hold all of the data in memory in between function calls or regenerate the iterator for the second function.

Now, if your functions were generators (that yield back to your code after consuming some small number of items from the input), you could make it work with `itertools.tee`. There might also be some other partial workarounds if you can call one or both of your functions with various parts of the input data at a time and then somehow compile the results of the repeated calls together into the desired output. Otherwise you're probably out of luck

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if your functions are stateless, but still expect an iterable as argument, and that's the whole problem, then this should do:

```
for si in s:
    a([si['a']])
    b([si['b']])
```

Comment: well, they need the whole iterator to generate output. Like you cannot add to a trie once it's generated because it's read only after that.

Comment: Well, if the functions are really stateless, then I don't see how this shouldn't work. Either that, or there's still something we need to learn about your problem

Comment: alright, replace `a` with `def a(iterable): return marisa_trie.Trie(iterable)`.  So I was wrong when saying they are stateless. They expect the whole iterable to generate output and then it's read only after that.  An example is from this package: https://github.com/kmike/marisa-trie

Comment: I think the only important part there is if `marisa_trie.Trie(iterable)` returns the same as `[marisa_trie.Trie([x]) for x in iterable]`. Then you can call `a` and `b` separately for each key, and this works.

Comment: That would generate `n` tries for `n` items in the iterable.  Basically I want one object at the end, and you cannot pass another iterable to it once it's finished with the first one.